# facebook-php-sdk return array, how use it?

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, sdk

i have made a facebook graph api request with php,and it have returned this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K87oa.png)

how can i access to the data using php array?
i have tryed with "var_dump($msgid['data']);" but does not work. Any solutions?

Comment: It's not an array. Try: `$result->backingData['data'][0]->name` ?

Comment: @OfirBaruch with your method the result is (Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property Facebook\GraphObject::$backingData) i'm sorry.

Comment: Oh, right - it's a protected property, which means you can't access it. Are you sure that it's a legit output you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved using this code, thank you evryone for helping me:

```
$request = (new FacebookRequest($session,'GET', 'me?fields=groups'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```